# Need some help with missing space, root is full

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage

Running Ubuntu 18.04 server as a storage server

So when I run `df -h`  I see my root disk is 100% full, I got 231MB left, however I just installed a fresh install a month ago, with no other installs than smb.

```
~$ df -h
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          769M  6.8M  762M   1% /run
/dev/sda2                      219G  208G  231M 100% /
tmpfs                          3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                          3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop1                      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/sda1                      511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdd1                      2.7T  2.3T  346G  87% /media/data1
```

So I then run `sudo du -ch --exclude=./media` And it output 7.3G

Can anybody help me? I never seen this before.

```
:/$ sudo du -ch --exclude=./media
7.3G    .
7.3G    total
```

`sudo ncdu --exclude /media` gives same result. I can't seem to find where the space is used.

`sudo du -hs --exclude=./media` gives some files not active and same 7.3G used.

Comment: Abstracting from the question, you can see here, why it's good to have a partitioned installation. (It protects system stability and also introduces disk usage clarity.)

Comment: So true, And this is the hard way to learn, thanks :)

Comment: Btw, take a look what's going on in `/media` (I guess that's what you mean). By some mount and related misconfigs there might be stuff residing and eating up your space. And take into consideration that the things may hide beneath the mounted sdd at `/media/data1`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some deleted files which are kept open by some process.

One possibility is rebooting (all processes will terminate and close their files, freeing space).

Otherwise you can do this (there almost certainly is a better way, but this I tested on an Ubuntu 18.04-LTS as you asked)

```
find /proc -type l -exec ls -la \{\} \; 2>&1 | grep "/proc/[0-9]*/fd/.*deleted"
```

This will show something like:

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov 18 08:16 /proc/1708/fd/139 -> /run/dovecot/login-master-notifycd7e64fd0dc27812 (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov 18 08:16 /proc/1708/fd/172 -> /run/dovecot/login-master-notify5d694b1832885980 (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov 18 08:16 /proc/1708/fd/177 -> /run/dovecot/login-master-notify03874675ec133d66 (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Nov 17 20:09 /proc/2160/fd/9 -> /tmp/.ZendSem.3acXWO (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec 16 06:39 /proc/10669/fd/9 -> /tmp/.ZendSem.3acXWO (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec 16 06:39 /proc/10670/fd/9 -> /tmp/.ZendSem.3acXWO (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec 16 06:39 /proc/10671/fd/9 -> /tmp/.ZendSem.3acXWO (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec 16 06:39 /proc/10672/fd/9 -> /tmp/.ZendSem.3acXWO (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Dec 17 00:01 /proc/10673/fd/9 -> /tmp/.ZendSem.3acXWO (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 mysql mysql 64 Dec 17 00:01 /proc/24928/fd/5 -> /tmp/ibZsXZWE (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 mysql mysql 64 Dec 17 00:01 /proc/24928/fd/6 -> /tmp/ibY4kIrj (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 mysql mysql 64 Dec 17 00:01 /proc/24928/fd/7 -> /tmp/ibhdYqWX (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 mysql mysql 64 Dec 17 00:01 /proc/24928/fd/8 -> /tmp/ib1PJXXg (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 mysql mysql 64 Dec 17 00:01 /proc/24928/fd/12 -> /tmp/ibuELYLV (deleted)
```

which tells me that MySQL and dovecot are eating "hidden space". So in this example I could try restarting first Dovecot, then MySQL, etc., and see when (*...the service stopping takes an inordinately long time with lots of disk thrashing, after which...*) space gets freed

## update

I had overlooked this in your question: "*with no other installs than smb*". Try restarting *that* straight away.

You might have VFS logging active, or a high debug level.

This actually happened to my $PFY once, we had debug turned on to check on a Windows 10 quirk (long since solved by SMB4 by the way), the log had overshot five gigabytes, and he *simply deleted the log*.

So Samba kept writing to the now invisible log file, which kept silently growing. We realized what had happened when some fifty Gbs had disappeared, while we were blaming users filling the space with junk (*they were doing that, too*).

## update 1.5

One way to make space "disappear" is this.

Suppose you have a file server and have the data on `/var/media`. There is some 250 GB of files. Then you decide to add another disk or replace with a larger disk via RAID sync plus expand, or whatever.

So in stage 2 you have temporarily an empty /mnt/otherdisk holding 8 TB of free space and you happily **copy** those 250 GB on the new disk/partition, permissions, ACL and all.

When you're done you obviously want to reuse the old configuration, scripts, backups and what not, so you mount the *new* partition over the *old* directory -- *but forget to free it first*. So now `/var/media` has 250 GB of newly copied files and 7.75 GB of free space -- but the original 250 GB are still beneath it all, and their space has not been freed.

To free the space you would need to

```
umount /var/media && (
    mv /var/media /var/old-media
    mkdir /var/media # create a new "/var/media"
    chown --reference /var/old-media /var/media
    chmod --reference /var/old-media /var/media
    mount /var/media
)
```

Now if `/var/old-media` really contains data, you can compare its contents (it's probably now obsolete, but who knows) with that of `/var/media`.

## update 2

Okay, the reboot fixed nothing, so the files *must* be there. Possibly in `lost+found` but the filesystem is now clean, so they *have* to be there (but just to check every step - can you also post the mount options?)

Try:

```
du -kx -d2 / | sort -n
```

to get the disk contents (okay, also `media`). That will get you the size of all root subtrees. If you see some subtree larger than it should be, except for `/media` of course, you can drill down. I have a large `/home/lserni` for example:

```
du -kx -d1 /home/lserni | sort -n
```

If the space is *still* unaccountably occupied, then reboot in single mode and run a `fsck`.

I will *not* readily believe you've a filesystem so messed up, that it *only* shows in the occupied space and yet `fsck` cannot fix it!

Comment: Thank you for input, I did a full system reboot, and still no change.
the only config files we use is the SMB config file and some cron jobs. Do you think a fresh re-install would be the way to go. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: It's past bedtime in my TZ, but I'll try messing up a test VM later tomorrow...

Comment: All seems normal in the content list, her are the bottom lines <code>851824  /lib
1148520 /usr
7016120 /</code>

Comment: Okay, last possibility. Unmount /media and the other mount points (one at a time). The resulting directories should now be empty. Are they?